# Get name of property

Tags: c#

```
var person = new Person();
Do(person.Firstname);

static void Do(object prop)
{
    //find out "Firstname"...
}
```

I would like to find out the name of a property, **where I have no access** to its parent object (person as above). Is it possible?

Comment: Do you want to find out the `Firstname` of the person or do you basically need a string `"Firstname"`?

Comment: You would have to have a separate parameter for the "name".  There's nothing stopping someone from passing `Do(4)` in which case there is not a "name" to get.

Comment: If you add what you need the name for, perhaps you can get an answer that's actually helpful.

Comment: Out of curiosity, what do you need this for?

Answer (score 1):

No, it's not possible. Your `Person.Firstname` is only a value. That value knows nothing about it's location(s) or origin in the code.

Comment: By your logic, passing `int x` into a function makes it impossible to find out that it's an `int`.

Comment: @devRicher: That's not the same at all. `Firstname` is a string. That's all the function `Do` can know about it. It doesn't know it's a string that happens to be a property of `Person` called `Firstname`. Which is what the OP wants to know. That would have to be passed separately.

Answer (score 1):

In C# 6 you can use `nameof`, but you'd have to use it before you pass it to `Do`:

```
Do(nameof(person.Firstname));

static void Do(object prop)
{
    // prop is the string Firstname
}
```

If you need the value and the name, you'd have to pass both as separate arguments:

```
Do(person.FirstName, nameof(person.Firstname));

static void Do(object prop, string name)
{
    // name is the string Firstname
    // prop is the value of person.Firstname
}
```

Comment: Ok thanks! It might work if nothing else is possible, I will check it up...

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps an approach like this may help you:

```
static void Do<TEntity, TProp>(TEntity entity, Expression<Func<TEntity, TProp>> property)
{
    var member = property.Body as MemberExpression;

    if (member != null)
    {
        var propertyName = member.Member.Name;
        var propertyValue = property.Compile()(entity);

        //Do something.
    }
}
```

Then you would be able to do things like this:

```
Do(person, p => p.FirstName);
Do(person, p => p.LastName);
```

Answer (score 0):

Can't really do it with a property, but you can do it with a method, including a method with does exactly what the property does.  For example

```
class Person
{
    public string GetName() { return "John Doe"; }
}

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var p = new Person();
        Do(p.GetName);  //Notice no () after GetName
    }


    static void Do(Func<string> f)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(String.Format("The caller sent the value '{0}' via a method named {1}", f.Invoke(), f.Method.Name);
    }


}
```